# TypeError: $.debounce is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am using this code:

```
function resizeJquerySteps() {
    $('.wizard .content').animate({
        height: $('.body.current').outerHeight()
    }, 'slow');
}

$(window).resize($.debounce(250, resizeJquerySteps));
```

And receiving this error `TypeError: $.debounce is not a function` is there another way to write this with no error?

Comment: Include a debounce function?

Comment: Where did you get that code? You surely missed to load a library.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This function defined in some library
like this http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.js

You need to include this library into your project.
See example here http://jsfiddle.net/hYsRh/4/

```
$(window).scroll($.debounce( 250, true, function(){
  $('#scrollMsg').html('SCROLLING!');
} ) );
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 4):

**For me debounce is working on added below script in HTML:**

```
<script src="http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.js"></script>
```

**And js code is:-**

```
 $("#confirmNewPassword").on("keyup keypress",($.debounce(500, function () { console.log("working debauncing")})))
```

Hope this will work fine for you as well.
Thanks.

Comment: This is basically a repetition of the accepted answer.