# Debounce error, "TypeError: $.debounce is not a function"

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery's debounce functionality but nothing I'm trying seems to work.

I've tried two different methods of calling debounce but neither seems to work. When I use the normal keyup function without debounce it works perfectly. I'm getting this error:
    TypeError: $.debounce is not a function

I've also tried including this (http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.js) js file as per this ([TypeError: $.debounce is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730628/typeerror-debounce-is-not-a-function)) thread but that didn't work either. Then I get this error:

```
callback.apply is not a function
```

I tried these methods:

```
$('#postalCodeInput').keyup($.debounce(function() {
    console.log('Key up with debounce');
}, 300));

    $('#postalCodeInput').keyup( $.debounce( 300, console.log('Key up with 
debounce') ) );
```

Comment: In what order do you include jQuery and this other plugin file?

Comment: @Taplar jQuery is first

Comment: Your issue may be with your second statement.  You are not passing a method in as the second argument.  You're passing the result of `console.log()` to it, which is undefined.  And if it tries to do undefined.apply(), then (boom)

Comment: @Taplar Thanks so much. That is working perfectly. I wonder why the first method isn't working though.

Comment: You have the arguments in the wrong order in the first one. `300` should be first.